# How to store app settings in iOS, like INI / CONF?

Tags: ios, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I am starting with iOS programming. I have a question hope you can help.

I have a test app as an rss reader that reads from a URL.  For example: abc.com/feed

I want to store some data in a setting file like INI on Windows or CONF on Linux, example:

```
URL = abc.com/feed
NumberOfItem = 10
Interval = 3 # minus
```

What kind of file does an iOS app use to store it's settings?  Is there any method/class/API/... which supports read/write on it?

P.S.  I am using **Titanium** at Appcelerator.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Properties.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module

Answer (score 1):

You can save data in the `NSUserDefaults` the complete [API-Documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003764)

To save some kind of data in the `NSUserDefaults` simply call `[[NSUsererDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myObject forKey:@"myObjectKey"]`.

To read the data call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myObjectKey"]`

Answer (score 1):

I use property lists (.plist), essentially an xml file, that can be read and written by the NSDictionary (and all its variants). For simple settings , as @Tobi suggests, NSUserDefaults. For larger, more complex datasets, i go with .plists. For each class that needs to persist, i create a +(id) loadFromDictionary and -(NSDictionary*) asDictionary method.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store simple data you can use `NSUserDefaults`
[NSUserDefaults Example](http://www.developerfeed.com/ios/snippet/using-nsuserdefaults-store-settings-ios)

Comment: Thanks for your reply however I am not use Xcode, I am using Titanium.